# Python 3.8 if, else command not working, just goes to the if no matter what

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

The function I wrote has an if, else statement. It seems like it ignores the if, else statement completely.

```
def start():
    task = input("Would you like to begin?\n>>>")
    if task == "Yes" or "yes":
        rate()
    else:
        quit()
```

No matter what I put in the input it automatically performs the function rate() instead of quit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since python conditional expressions are left-associated (read from left to right - there are some exceptions), the condition of your if statement is interpreted as

> (task == "Yes") or ("yes")

because `==` only expects one more expression to the right.

Hence even `task == ("Yes" or "yes")` would fail, due to the `or` operator expecting boolean values as input (left and right side). Since `bool("Yes")` evaluates to `True` the first object is returned by the `or` operator, here `"Yes"`. That value is then used in the `==` comparison.

What you might want to do is:

> if task.lower() == "yes"

or

> if task in ["Yes", "yes"]

Comment: Nit: not *all* operators are left-associative. `2**3**4` is parsed as `2 ** (3 ** 4)`. Parsing this as `task == ("Yes or "yes")` wouldn't work either, as it would trivially reduce to `task == "Yes"`, ignoring `"yes"` altogether.

Comment: Indeed - not all all operators are left-associative - though most are :)

Comment: But, as I also pointed out, this isn't just a matter of associativity, but of the semantics of both `or` and `==`.

Comment: `==` expects one expression to the right. Indeed `("Yes" or "yes") ` evaluates to `Yes`because it is the first value to evaluate to `True` by or (which expects boolean expression to the left and right) - which is also what I pointed out - soon in a more elaborated version.

Comment: All binary operators expect an expression on the left and on the right. Associativity is only relevant with operators having the same precedence (like `3 + 5 - 7`). `==` and `or` have *different* precedence, though.